# Qt5 to stream two videos simultaneously

Tags: camera, qt5, multimedia

I created a GUI to play two videos from two cameras, one camera is a USB camera, and another one is integrated in my laptop. My code is simple, I have three files:

1. main.cpp

> ```
> #include "mainwindow.h"
> #include <QApplication>
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     QApplication app(argc, argv);
>     MainWindow window;
>     window.show();
>
>     return app.exec();
> }
> ```

2. mainwindow.h

> ```
> #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
> #define MAINWINDOW_H
>
> #include <QMainWindow>
> #include <QCamera>
> #include <QCameraInfo>
> #include <QCameraImageCapture>
>
> namespace Ui {
>     class MainWindow;
> }
>
> class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
>
>     Q_OBJECT
>
> public:
>     explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
>     ~MainWindow();
>
> private:
>     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
>     QList <QCameraInfo> camList;
>     QCamera *camera1;
>     QCamera *camera2;
>
> private slots:
>     void onCameraChanged(int);
> };
> #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
> ```

3. mainwindow.cpp

> ```
> #include "mainwindow.h"
> #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
>
> MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
>     QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
>     ui->setupUi(this);
>
>     camera1 = NULL;
>     camera2 = NULL;
>
>     connect(ui->cameraComboBox,static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),this,
>             &MainWindow::onCameraChanged);
>
>     camList = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
>     for(QList <QCameraInfo>::iterator it = camList.begin();it!=camList.end();++it) {
>         ui->cameraComboBox->addItem(it->description());
>     }
> }
>
> MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
>     delete ui;
> }
>
> void MainWindow::onCameraChanged(int idx) {
>     if(camera1 != NULL) {
>         camera1->stop();
>     }
>     qDebug() << idx;
>     camera1 = new QCamera(camList.at(idx),this);
>     camera1->setViewfinder(ui->mainView);
>     camera1->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);
>     camera1->start();
>
>     if(camera2 != NULL) {
>         camera2->stop();
>     }
>     camera2 = new QCamera(camList.at(idx+1),this);
>     camera2->setViewfinder(ui->submainView);
>     camera2->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);
>     camera2->start();
> }
> ```

I have deleted irrelevant code. Of course I have this in the *.pro file:

> QT       += multimedia multimediawidgets

My code compiles correctly, but it can only stream one video (camera1), and the other one shows nothing. The error I got is

```
CameraBin error: "Error starting streaming on device '/dev/video1'."
CameraBin error: "Could not negotiate format"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to stream the other (/dev/video1) separately?

Comment: @agold, oooops, I just found the integrated camera doesn't work anymore. It worked well last night, I use a combo box to choose which camera to stream.